I have a doubt vs. I have a question
I'm a native english speaker so maybe this isn't the appropriate forum. That being said, I have many Indian colleagues that when they have a question about something they'll say "I have a doubt" instead of "I have a question". I'm curious where this originated? I'm guessing this is what is taught in school?

Hard to answer. As we generally use: I doubt that x. For the suit thing, I think I would just tell them. :) Pretend surprise.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please post each question separately. Yes, they're both about Indian patterns, but that's not enough relation to make them "one question." Yes, "I have a doubt" is a common Indian-English usage; you can find many results about it on this site and elsewhere. But the best answer to your question might be on the separate Stack Exchange "English Language and Usage": https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348231/what-is-the-history-of-the-indianenglish-usage-of-doubt-to-mean-question

When questioning means challenging, doubting can substitute well. When it means asking for information, "I have a doubt" is wrong because it expresses disagreement, that something is wrong.

@AndyBonner How can that supposedly Indian English thing be verified? English speakers generally use verbs, I doubt that whatever. Also, the question is asking for an opinion.

@Lambie Well, speaking from personal experience for my part, as it sounds like the OP is. Searching ELL and ELU for "have a doubt" should also show that it happens. The present question has several issues ("should I correct people's pronunciation" is a social rather than linguistic ask, and the assumption that other pronunciations are "wrong" is not a secure one), but the most answerable core is "how did it evolve," and the ELU link I pasted addresses that.

@Andy Bonner "suit" for suite is most definitely a mistake. It's a different word in any English. But the other one I don't think is even verifiable. We just don't use it even if grammatically it is not wrong. We say: I doubt that this code is right. Not: I have a doubt about this code being right. We might say: I have my doubts about this.

@Lambie We say thus, assuming that "we" are AmE or BrE (one of the first things I did after seeing this was see whether we have a policy that we only support, or write from a perspective of, these. I didn't see one, and the on-topic page mentions "dialect differences.") But the question is about IndE context, and yes, I regularly get things like "Do you have a moment? I have a few doubts about X. First of all... [list of questions]."

@Lambie (I once had a real misunderstanding when this was paired with the tendency to delete "a" in "a few [of something]": "Shravan, are we ready for the release?" "I have few doubts." I took this as "For sure; any misgiving I might have are few." But he meant "No, I still have a few unresolved questions."

@AndyBonner This:  "Do you have a moment? I have a few doubts about X. First of all.. sounds fine to me because doubt is in the plural.

@Lambie Well, it's still not an expression that I would use as AmE; there, I would say doubt is uncountable and expresses a mood or stance. I could have given the example as singular, "I have a doubt," and within IndE a reasonable response could be "Ok, what is your doubt," i.e. what is your question, where AmE/BrE "I have some [or zero article] doubt" is reasonably met with "Ok, what is your doubt about?" I could imagine, even within AmE/BrE, speaking of multiple "doubts" on multiple topics, just as I might have "several fears" or even, waxing a tich poetic, "several joys," but I'd call...

... that a sort of "extended usage," rather than a primary one.

I’m voting to close this question because the use of English really belongs on [english.se]

As I'm sure you're aware as a native speaker, they are not the same. A doubt is an uncertainty. If we have a doubt about something, that might mean we do not think it to be a good idea. It suggests that, unless someone addresses that doubt and allays any fears we have, our view of something is negative.
A question doesn't necessarily infer a 'doubt'. We ask questions for lots of reasons. Sometimes we ask a question because we are seeking information that will address a doubt, but other times we ask a question for additional information that will not affect a decision we have already made. For example, you might book a vacation having heard all you need to make that decision, but still have some additional questions like "what time is dinner served?".
The fact that there are contexts/situations where they could be used interchangeably (ie asking a question that addresses a doubt) is the most likely reason that some non-native speakers are using them synonymously. It's also a possibility that the word in their own language which translates as 'doubt' is not as strong. The English word most often tends to imply a concern or apprehension, but an 'uncertainty' is really just a lack of information leading to an indecision. So perhaps it's not as unusual to use them interchangeably as it seems to native English speakers?
